# Обновление данных в таблице с помощью mysql-триггера

Tags: mysql, триггер

Есть две таблицы: cdr и call_kontrid.

```
В cdr поля: calldate, dst, cnum, kontrid.
В call_kontrid поля: exten, telid, kontrid, timenow.
```

По умолчанию, в **cdr** в поле kontrid проставляется null. А в **call_kontrid** в поле kontrid добавляется значения.

И есть триггер, который после добавления новой строки в cdr, должен достать kontrid из таблицы **call_kontrid** и обновить значение в соответствующей строке в таблице **cdr**. Подскажите пожалуйста, как это сделать?? Вот мой код.

```
BEGIN
  SET @kontrid = (SELECT kontrid FROM call_kontrid 
  WHERE timenow = new.calldate AND exten = new.cnum AND telid = new.dst);
  IF(@kontrid IS NOT NULL)THEN 
    UPDATE cdr SET kontrid = @kontrid WHERE calldate = new.calldate;
  END IF;
END
```

Всем заранее огромное спасибо за помощь!

Comment: И по какому же принципу триггер должен понять, что именно вот из этой записи таблицы `call_kontrid` надо взять значение `kontrid` для обновления таблицы `cdr`?

Comment: Cравнив calldate и timenow, dst и telid, cnum и exten.

Comment: Вот всё это - в текст вопроса, пожалуйста. И не тезисами, как в комментарии, а подробно. Может быть, даже с примерами, если слов не хватит. А то, знаете ли, предложение сравнить calldate (судя по имени поля, чисто дата) и timenow (чисто время) маразмом отдаёт...

Comment: Добавил код в вопрос

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CREATE TRIGGER update_kontrid_on_cdr
BEFORE INSERT ON cdr 
FOR EACH ROW 
SET NEW.kontrid = (SELECT kontrid
                   FROM call_kontrid
                   WHERE timenow = new.calldate 
                     AND exten = new.cnum 
                     AND telid = new.dst
                  );
```

Данный триггер БЕЗУСЛОВНО добавит расчётное значение - даже если в запросе его задать, заданное будет заменено на расчётное. Если это не нужно, то:

```
CREATE TRIGGER update_kontrid_on_cdr
BEFORE INSERT ON cdr 
FOR EACH ROW 
SET NEW.kontrid = (SELECT kontrid
                   FROM call_kontrid
                   WHERE timenow = NEW.calldate 
                     AND exten = NEW.cnum 
                     AND telid = NEW.dst
                     AND NEW.kontrid IS NULL
                  );
```

Comment: Благодарю! Но, почему то не могу сохранить изменения в триггере, пишет "updating of new row in not  allowed in after trigger"

Comment: Перевести сообщение не пробовал? ну или хотя бы сравнить с моим текстом? у меня он `BEFORE INSERT` - только там можно менять псевдотаблицу `NEW`.

Comment: Пробовал, ну так а если мне необходимо чтобы триггер срабатывал после добавления новой записи? Я sql практически не знаю, поэтому и обратился сюда за помощью.

Comment: Прошу прощения) Я понял свою ошибку

Comment: *мне необходимо чтобы триггер срабатывал после добавления новой записи* Тебе необходимо, чтобы триггер срабатывал ПРИ ДОБАВЛЕНИИ. Надо понимать, что добавление будет ОДНО, хоть с триггером, хоть без. А не два - сперва силами запроса, потом силами триггера.